# How to sort an array of ASCII hex strings numerically?

Tags: sorting, perl

I feel like this is a simple problem. But I am stuck and to be honest my mind is having an info overload at the moment. I am also new to Perl and I'm still trying to explore it.

So I have a variable that contains a string:

```
$strings =
"3A
1B
2A
5A
4B"
```

then I converted it into an array by splitting it:

```
@split_array = split("\n", $strings);

print @split_array . "\n";
```

Output:

```
3A
1B
2A
5A
4B
```

Now, I want to sort this array in ascending order.

Here's what I tried:

```
@sorted_array = sort @split_array;
```

Expected Output:

```
1B
2A
3A
4B
5A
```

but the output is still the same.

I apologize if I missed something obvious here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input `$strings` looks very odd to me. Does it multilined string? If yes, it should be enclosed within double quotes. `use strict; use warnings;` would highlight most of the errors here.

Comment: I've already edited it. Apologies

Comment: Ok, so you already split here with `'\n'` now. So what the problem now you're facing?

Comment: It's better to show the complete and minimal program you are using. You've likely got something wrong in parts of the code you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strings = "3A 
1B 
2A 
5A 
4B";

my @split_array = split(" ", $strings);

print "@split_array\n";

my @sorted_array = sort @split_array;
print "@sorted_array\n";
```

output is

```
3A 1B 2A 5A 4B
1B 2A 3A 4B 5A
```

Note that this is doing a *string* sort, rather than a *numeric* sort. It works in this instance because you are only sorting 2 character ASCII hex strings that happen to sort in proper numeric order. If the format is different, say the values contain 3 character ASCII hex, that string sort will not work properly.

For example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strings = "3A 
100 
1B 
2A 
5A 
4B";

my @split_array = split(" ", $strings);

print "@split_array\n";

my @sorted_array = sort @split_array;
```

outputs

```
3A 100 1B 2A 5A 4B
100 1B 2A 3A 4B 5A
```

To fix that you need to do a proper numeric sort. That means converting the ASCII hex numbers into their binary equivalent.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strings = "3A 
100 
1B 
2A 
5A 
4B";

my @split_array = split(" ", $strings);

print "@split_array\n";

my @sorted_array = sort @split_array;
print "@sorted_array\n";

my @numeric_sorted_array = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } @split_array;
print "@numeric_sorted_array\n";
```

output is

```
3A 100 1B 2A 5A 4B
100 1B 2A 3A 4B 5A
1B 2A 3A 4B 5A 100
```

The key here is the `sort { hex $a <=> hex $b }` expression -- this converts the ASCII hex into binary with the `hex` function, then uses the `<=>` operator to carry out a numeric sort.

**[EDIT]**

If the input data contains non-hex digits, you need to clean up the data before using the `hex` function to prevent the `Illegal hexadecimal digit` warning message as shown below

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings;  print hex("10Y") . "\n"'
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Y' ignored at -e line 1.
16
```

If the requirement is to have a sorted list of ASCII hex digits with *all* non-hex digits removed, the code can be updated like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strings = "3A 
100 
1BY
2A 
5A 
4B";

my @split_array = split(" ", $strings);

print "Unsorted: @split_array\n";

my @sorted_array = sort @split_array;
print "Default sort: @sorted_array\n";

my @numeric_sorted_array = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } @split_array;
print "Numeric Sort: @numeric_sorted_array\n";

my @cleaned_numeric_sorted_array = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } 
                                   map  { s/[^0-9a-f]+//ir  } 
                                   @split_array;
print "Cleaned: @cleaned_numeric_sorted_array\n";
```

output is

```
Unsorted: 3A 100 1BY 2A 5A 4B
Default sort: 100 1BY 2A 3A 4B 5A
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Y' ignored at /tmp/fred.pl line 19.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Y' ignored at /tmp/fred.pl line 19.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Y' ignored at /tmp/fred.pl line 19.
Numeric Sort: 1BY 2A 3A 4B 5A 100
Cleaned: 1B 2A 3A 4B 5A 100
```

the magic happens with the `map` function -- this removes all non-hex digits before feeding the data into `sort`

Comment: Woah, the 2nd solution worked for me. I see.... So that's why......

Comment: I have a question though. What if the last letter is not A or B. What if it is "M"?.

I got a warning that says "Illegial hexadecimal digit 'M' ignored at file.pl line N"

Comment: The `hex` function will stop once it gets an invalid hex digit. So `perl -e ' print hex("10Y") . "\n" '` prints `16`. Only problem is is you have `use warnings` enabled (which you should all th etime) you will get a warning message. So `perl -e 'use strict; use warnings;  print hex("10Y") . "\n"'` will print `Illegal hexadecimal digit 'Y' ignored at -e line 1.` to stderr

Comment: Answer updated to deal with non-hex digits.

Comment: Very good point. code updated

Answer (score 2):

Look for the below working code:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string =
"3A
1B
2A
5A
4B";

my @before = split("\n", $string);
my @after = sort @before;
print Dumper(\@after);
```